# Misunderstanding in the proof that the sum of subspaces is the smallest containing subspace.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

So if $V_1,...,V_n$ are subspaces of $M$ then $V_1+...+V_n$ is the smallest subspace of $M$ containing $V_1,...,V_n$

The proof is that clearly $V_1,...,V_n$ are all contained in $V_1+...+V_n$

Then the converse/ If every subspace of $M$ containing $V_1,...,V_n$ contains $V_1+...+V_n$ **but this isn't very clear to me**

But the thing that **unclearest to me** is how the author concludes that thus $V_1+...+V_n$ is the smallest subspace of $V$ containing $V_1,...,V_n$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing to understand: if **any** subspace containing $\;V_1\,,\,V_2\,,\,\ldots,V_n\;$ also contains $V_1+V_2+\ldots+V_n\;$, then *clearly* it is the minimal (wrt inclusion) such space.

Now, if $\;W\;$ is *any* subspace containing $\;V_1,...,V_n\;$ then, as $\;W\;$ is closed under addition, it **must** contain also any linear combination of elements in the $\;V_1,...,V_n\;$ , in particular it **must** contain all the sums of the form $\;v_1+\ldots+v_n\;,\;\;v_i\in V_i\;$, and thus it contains the whole space sum $\;V_1+\ldots+V_n\;$

Comment: The first part is not clear.

Comment: If $\;V_1+\ldots +V_n\le T\;$ for **any** subspace $\;T\;$ containing each $\;V_1\;$, then the sum is **the** minimal such *subspace*, right? Of course, we're assuming you already know/proved that $\;V_1+\ldots +V_n\;$ is a subspace as long as each $\;V_i\;$ is.